# I'm trying to simulate the Monty Hall problem in Matlab. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: matlab, statistics

As stated in title. I know that the probability of winning if one swaps doors in this problem should be roughly 66% but I seem to get answers implying a 33% success rate in cases where the player swaps as well as where the player does not swap. The variables associated with these two values are swapwinratio and noswapwinratio and these both consistently return values of roughly 0.33 at runtime. In tests, I've run sample numbers of 5000 to 10,000. Here is my code:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

numsamps = input("Enter number of samples to take. \n");

if(mod(numsamps, 1) || numsamps < 1)
    error("Must be a positive integer number.");
end

wins = 0;
swapwins = 0;
noswapwins = 0;
swaps = 0;
noswaps = 0;
for i = 1:numsamps
    doors = 1:3;
    host = ceil(3 * rand());
    player = ceil(3 * rand());
    p1 = player;
    doors(player) = 0;
    goat = ceil(2 * rand());
    for j = goat:3
        if(doors(j) ~= 0)
            doors(j) = 0;
            break;
        end
    end
    swap = floor(2 * rand());
    if(swap)
        ind = find(doors ~= 0);
        player = doors(ind);
        swaps = swaps + 1;
    else
        noswaps = noswaps + 1;
    end
    if(player == host)
        wins = wins + 1;
        if(swap)
            swapwins = swapwins + 1;
        else
            noswapwins = noswapwins + 1;
        end
    end
end

swapwinratio = swapwins/swaps;
noswapwinratio = noswapwins/noswaps;
```

Sorry if I've missed anything; this is my first time posting to stackoverflow!

Comment: `ceil(3 * rand())` is not such a good way of picking a random integer. Instead, use `randi(3)`.

Comment: Also, you have too many random numbers in each iteration. The location of the prize is random, and the picked door is random. If they match, go down one path where swapping is bad and staying is good. If they don't match, go down the other path where swapping is good and staying is bad. In the first case, the door that the host opens is irrelevant, neither has the prize; in the second case it is always the one without the prize.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks so much, I was able to fix it based on your advice!

Comment: Please consider answering your own question, it might be useful for future visitors.